# Python: how to open files from another directory git repo (locally cloned)?

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a Python module in a git repo and need to read files from another directory in the same repo. I have the repo cloned locally, so my module can currently open local files saved in the same directory as my module, but I need to be able to open other files from other directories within the same repo. What's the best way I can do this? Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Assuming you're just trying to read a static file, you should be able to simply provide the full path to the target path, as per https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp Are you trying to get Python to issue `git` commands involving the target file?  `git` and `python` don't normally interact in funny ways.  What have you tried?

Comment: @Sarah you don't want to put in the full path, because the repo will be cloned to different locations on different machines, and those paths will break. Instead, use a relative path - `with open("../../data/datafile.txt", "r") as f: ...`

Comment: @SarahMesser I'm not trying to issue git commands within Python, just make it so the module can be ran on other computers and pull files from the folder in the git repo since a path to my locally-cloned repo would not work. Unless I'm incorrect with that statement. So far, I have worked to use a relative path, as MattDMo suggested.

Comment: Git isn't relevant here, since you already have the files. You just need to use a path that refers to the file. Note: Git isn't about *files*, Git is about *commits*. You clone a repository (which gets you all the commits), then you *check out* a commit, which extracts *all the files* from that commit: every commit contains a full copy of every file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how we do it where I work!

Lets say the directory looks like so:

```
User -|
      |-GitHub/-
               |- dir_1/
               |
               |- dir_2/ -
                        |- module_path_1/ -
                                        | - module.py
```

We are in dir_1, running our code from dir_1.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../dir_2/module_path_1")
from module import function1
```

And that should do it!